# Filter a grouped dataframe based on row value changes

Tags: python, pandas

Given this sample dataframe:

```
#%%
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#%%
df = pd.DataFrame({'dev_id': ['A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2','A2','A3','A3','A3','A3','A3'], 
'timestamp': ['2020-11-11 06:00:10.110','2020-11-11 06:00:25.075','2020-11-11 06:00:40.072','2020-11-11 06:00:55.071','2020-11-11 06:01:10.097','2020-11-11 06:00:10.110','2020-11-11 06:00:25.075','2020-11-11 06:00:40.072','2020-11-11 06:00:55.071','2020-11-11 06:01:10.097','2020-11-11 06:00:10.110','2020-11-11 06:00:25.075','2020-11-11 06:00:40.072','2020-11-11 06:00:55.071','2020-11-11 06:01:10.097'], 
'value1': [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1], 
'value2': [1,0,np.nan,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,np.nan]})
df
```

This yields:

```
    dev_id  timestamp               value1  value2
0   A1      2020-11-11 06:00:10.110 0       1.0
1   A1      2020-11-11 06:00:25.075 0       0.0
2   A1      2020-11-11 06:00:40.072 0       NaN
3   A1      2020-11-11 06:00:55.071 1       0.0
4   A1      2020-11-11 06:01:10.097 1       0.0
5   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:10.110 0       0.0
6   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:25.075 0       0.0
7   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:40.072 1       0.0
8   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:55.071 1       0.0
9   A2      2020-11-11 06:01:10.097 1       0.0
10  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:10.110 0       0.0
11  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:25.075 0       0.0
12  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:40.072 0       0.0
13  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:55.071 0       1.0
14  A3      2020-11-11 06:01:10.097 1       NaN
```

I need to output a new data frame that consists of only the rows of df that have a different value for `value1` and `value2`, grouped by dev_id. There are more, but I've simplified it for this question.

In the above example, I should get a dataframe that looks like:

```
idx dev_id  timestamp               value1  value2
3   A1      2020-11-11 06:00:55.071 1       0.0
5   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:10.110 0       0.0
7   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:40.072 1       0.0
10  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:10.110 0       0.0
13  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:55.071 0       1.0
14  A3      2020-11-11 06:01:10.097 1       0.0
```

Since those rows differ from the previous in value1 or 2

Ive done this:

```
# %%
# fill NaNs
df[['value1','value2']] = df[['value1','value2']].fillna(value=0).astype(int)
df
```

To fill any NaNs with 0s, which is acceptable in my use case, then I reset the columns to int dtype. Then, I'm doing this as the first step in figuring how to do this, but the results are NOT what I expect::

```
# %%
df[['value1-diff','value2-diff']] = df.groupby(['dev_id'])['value1','value2'].diff()
df

idx dev_id  timestamp               value1  value2  value1-diff value2-diff
0   A1      2020-11-11 06:00:10.110 0       1.0     NaN         NaN
1   A1      2020-11-11 06:00:25.075 0       0.0     0.0         -1.0
2   A1      2020-11-11 06:00:40.072 0       0.0     0.0         0.0
3   A1      2020-11-11 06:00:55.071 1       0.0     1.0         0.0
4   A1      2020-11-11 06:01:10.097 1       0.0     0.0         0.0
5   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:10.110 0       0.0     NaN         NaN
6   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:25.075 0       0.0     0.0         0.0
7   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:40.072 1       0.0     1.0         0.0
8   A2      2020-11-11 06:00:55.071 1       0.0     0.0         0.0
9   A2      2020-11-11 06:01:10.097 1       0.0     0.0         0.0
10  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:10.110 0       0.0     NaN         NaN
11  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:25.075 0       0.0     0.0         0.0
12  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:40.072 0       0.0     0.0         0.0
13  A3      2020-11-11 06:00:55.071 0       1.0     0.0         1.0
14  A3      2020-11-11 06:01:10.097 1       0.0     1.0         -1.0
```

I understand the top row, but why is index 5 and 10 NaN? Ultimately, I don't need the diff columns, I just need to filter the original dataframe down to just the rows that change from the previous row, but I'm trying to understand diff() and why it's performing this way

Comment: I think it's treating `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, etc. all as separate groups. The first entry in each group doesn't have a previous entry in the group, so its values become `NaN`.

Comment: Ah, yes I'm grouping by dev_id, so those are NaN just like the top row.